# XtraBackup for SST with Xtradb cluster

Tags: linux, mysql, xtrabackup, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm looking for some instructions/manual to set Percona Xtradb cluster with Xtrabackup for SST. Is there any configuration file where I need to provide login details for Xtrabackup script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any configuration file where I need to provide login details
>   for Xtrabackup script?

If you have tried that, take a look at the `innobackup.backup.log` on the donor, you will see something like this:

`innobackupex: Error: mysql child process has died: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mysql'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

It means that `/usr/bin/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup` is running as `mysql` user without any auth setting. So, what I have done to make it work is:

1. change the home folder of `mysql` user:

   ```
   usermod -m -d /home/mysql mysql
   ```
2. put the following into `/home/mysql/.my.cnf`:

   ```
   [mysql]
   user        = root
   password    = PA$$W0RD
   ```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtradb-cluster/+bug/982003

You can also provide the login credential by using [wsrep_sst_auth](http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=mysql_options_0.8) option (on the donor):

```
wsrep_sst_auth=root:PA$$W0RD
```